# Excel Unable to Display or Distinguish Text Strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, csv

I created a simple CSV file with only this exact text (quotes included):

```
"-2**31-1","-2**31"
```

How can I open this CSV file in Excel and get it to display exactly:

```
        A              B
1    -2**31-1       -2**31
```

The first value, especially, seems impossible to get to show up verbatim in A1, regardless of how I format the data.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a leading `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include an equal sign (`=`) before your quotes to force Excel to display each cell value as text.

Your file should look like this:

```
="-2**31-1",="-2**31"
```

and Excel will display it like this:

[image]

*Source:* [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/165052/5463636)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, I pasted your sample directly into a CSV file and it displays in Excel including both the apostrophe and the double quotes.  I want Excel to display exactly as I showed in my question.

Comment: @Vincent you're right, that solution won't work for what you're trying to do. See my updated answer for the correct method.